# Why is there an unexpected character on line 6 in C64 Basic?

Tags: basic, c64, commodore

PRG Studio says there is an unexpected character on line 6. But, I can't figure out why. I'm programming for the c64.

```
1 rem setup
3 holding = "nothing"
6 playing_game = true
10 rem intro
20 print "it is dark. you have hiked miles to get here."
30 gosub 10000 rem wait
40 print "you have come to explore the castle of chadon hill."
50 gosub 10000 rem wait
60 print "it is said to have many traps. it is abandoned."
70 gosub 10000 rem wait
80 print "nobody has ever came back out..."
90 gosub 10000 rem wait
10000 rem wait
10010 waitcount = 0
10020 while waitcount < 50: waitcount = waitcount + 1: next waitcount
10030 return
```

I tried to change the "" to '', but that didn't work, I tried changing true to "true". That did nothing.

Comment: Probably the underscore. I also doubt that you have true and false as boolean values.

Comment: Did you know that the machine only have 38911 bytes of memory available for BASIC? Not terabyte, gigabyte or megabyte.  Only 38 kilobytes. And that the BASIC interpreter have to read each byte of a name to find the variable in memory? Due to the limited memory and speed of the machine, the BASIC interpreter only uses the two first characters of a variable name. `A$` and `AA$` are different, but `AB$` and `ABC$` refers to the same location in memory.

Comment: @some Yes, I know.

Comment: Commands are only recognized if in upper case. The name of string variables must end with a `$`. There is no `true` or `while`. `holding`  contains a string, so should end with `$`, like `HO$`. Instead of burning cycles in wait, that depends on the speed of the machine, use the TI variable to get elapsed time in seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code won't work as you desire:

- C64 BASIC, like most early Microsoft-derived BASICS, used numeric `0` (for false) and `-1` (for true) for booleans.
- The underscore `_` was not one of the allowed characters; this is the source of the error message you're receiving.
- String variables required the string indicator, `$` - the variable `holding` is presumed to be numeric; to make it a string, name it `holding$`. I'm surprised you're not getting a type mismatch error in line 3.

Comment: Also, while you can write a variable name that is up to 80 characters, the BASIC interpreter uses only the first 2 characters for identification: The variables `A$` and `AA$` are different, but not `AB$` and `ABC$`.